# AttributedString with line break (\n) is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift3, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I am adding `Continue reading` in the last. If there is any line break in the text, the continue reading is not visible. Is this iOS specific bug or I am missing something?

```
let activityData.feed = "Hi this is \n \n stack overflow"

let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
                formattedString.normal(activityData.feed!).bold(LanguageManager.shared.getLocale(key: "Continue Reading"))
                labelFeed.attributedText = formattedString
```

Extension of attributed string

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    @discardableResult func bold(_ text:String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let attrs:[String:AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0), NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.CNS_BlueColor]
        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"\(text)", attributes:attrs)
        self.append(boldString)
        return self
    }

    @discardableResult func normal(_ text:String)->NSMutableAttributedString {
        let normal =  NSAttributedString(string: text)
        self.append(normal)
        return self
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are either not resizing the label to fit its contents or having a label with a fixed two-line height.

Comment: I'd say that's maybe you allowed only 2 lines on your label, or simply the height of the label/textview is not enough.

Comment: @the4kman, I verified that label's height is appropriate or not. I have tap gesture on label, on click label is expanding properly. Also I set the truncate to the middle(means continue reading will always shown in the end\).

Answer (score 8):

Did you try the html tag `<br>` instead of `\n` ? 
If you already have an attributedstring, take antvantage of the html tags.